# Facebook messenger platform: generic template with quick replies

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-send-api

I was looking at some pretty popular bots like "The Guardian" and i noticed that whenever you get a generic template reply from it it also displays some quick reply buttons (see the photo attached). How did "The Guardian Bot" achieve this? How he combined quick replies and a generic template? It must be two messages involved.

[image]

Comment: The bot posts first attachment, then menu. So ?

Comment: How exactly it works? It first sends the generic template and then quick reply? But in quick reply you must specify a title and title cant be empty.

Comment: So ? They've specified title :)

Comment: So what is the title?

Comment: there are 5 titles

Comment: It's just that, he has put the quick replies in a separate function which is automatically called after posting the generic template

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

Comment: I was wondering if you found the actual answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the bot in nodejs and I am using a node module called `messenger-bot` which makes it easier to call the messenger bot API. Here's my customized code for you

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const Bot = require('messenger-bot')
var bot = new Bot({
    token: 'your FB app token',
    verify: 'VERIFY_TOKEN'
})

bot.on('postback', (payload, reply) => {
    var postback = payload.postback.payload;
    if (postback == "yes") {

        function getQuickReplies() {
            console.log("in next function");
            var quick_list = {
                "text": "Check the next article?",
                "quick_replies": [{
                        "content_type": "text",
                        "title": "More stories",
                        "payload": "more stories"
                    },
                    {
                        "content_type": "text",
                        "title": "Sport",
                        "payload": "sport"
                    },
                    {
                        "content_type": "text",
                        "title": "Business",
                        "payload": "business"
                    }

                ]
            };
            bot.getProfile(payload.sender.id, (err, profile) => {
                if (err) throw err
                text = quick_list;
                bot.sendMessage(payload.sender.id, text) {//this prints quick replies
                    console.log("sending message");
                }
            });
        }

        //calling generic template

        var generic_temp = "message": {
            "attachment": {
                -- - your code-- -
            }
        }; //generic template refer - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template

        bot.getProfile(payload.sender.id, (err, profile) => {
            if (err) throw err
            bot.sendMessage(payload.sender.id, generic_temp) {//this prints generic template
                console.log("sending message");
            }
        });

        //calling the quick replies once the generic template is sent

        getQuickReplies(); //to avoid async execution issue, we will have to put this in a function.

    }
});
```

references - [Generic template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template), [Quick replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies), [messenger-bot npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/messenger-bot)

Hope this helps! Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Dialogflow, return similar Json Object in backend to achieve the result:

```
 {
  "facebook": {
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic",
        "elements":[
           {
            "title":"Welcome!",
            "image_url":"https://petersfancybrownhats.com/company_image.png",
            "subtitle":"We have the right hat for everyone.",
            "default_action": {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "https://petersfancybrownhats.com/view?item=103",
              "webview_height_ratio": "tall"
            },
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"web_url",
                "url":"https://petersfancybrownhats.com",
                "title":"View Website"
              },{
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Start Chatting",
                "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
              }              
            ]      
          }
        ]
      }
    },
     "quick_replies":[
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Search",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png"
      },
      {
        "content_type":"location"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick replies are usually  accompanied by a 'text' property that sends a text message before the quick reply. It appears you can substitute any template for that. For example, here is the request body for a generic template carousel with quick replies:

```
{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"{{PSID}}"
  },
  "messaging_type": "response",
  "message":{
        "quick_replies": [
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Quick Reply 1",
        "image_url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/master/images/Messenger_Icon.png",
        "payload":"payload1"
      },
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Quick Reply 2",
        "payload":"payload2"
      }
    ],

    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic",
        "elements":[
          {
            "title":"This is a generic template",
            "subtitle":"Plus a subtitle!",
            "image_url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/master/images/Messenger_Icon.png",
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Postback Button",
                "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>"
              }
            ]      
          }, 
          {
            "title":"Another generic template",
            "subtitle":"Plus a subtitle!",
            "image_url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/master/images/Messenger_Icon.png",
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Postback Button",
                "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>"
              }
            ]      
          },
          {
            "title":"And another!",
            "subtitle":"Plus a subtitle!",
            "image_url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/master/images/Messenger_Icon.png",
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Postback Button",
                "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>"
              }
            ]      
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NEW UPDATE**

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic",
        "elements":[
           {
            "title":"Welcome!",
            "image_url":"https://petersfancybrownhats.com/company_image.png",
            "subtitle":"We have the right hat for everyone.",
            "default_action": {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "https://petersfancybrownhats.com/view?item=103",
              "webview_height_ratio": "tall"
            },
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"web_url",
                "url":"https://petersfancybrownhats.com",
                "title":"View Website"
              },{
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Start Chatting",
                "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
              }              
            ]      
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "quick_replies":[
      {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Red",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png"
      },{
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Green",
        "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/green.png"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```